# I want to extract only the red and blue lines or enhance these lines in the image provided for easier detection by my CNN model

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am trying to check if the photo in the image(**some ID card**) is forged or not, for that I have done some ELA transformation(found from Kaggle) on the original image which provide me with this image which has some red or blue lines if the "photo" in the image was spliced(copied and pasted another photo) to show if the photo in the image is forged but I want to extract or enhance these lines only and maybe be remove the other noise(white colored pixels and rest of the red, blue lines in the image), so that I can add them as some image preprocessing techniques and then pass the images to my model to have a better detection ability/accuracy.

Any suggestion would be helpful and Thanks in advance.

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

forged Image:

[image: forged Image]

forged image after ELA:

[image: forged image after ELA]

Comment: Can you post original image, please?

Comment: @toyotaSupra I have posted the original image as well

Comment: Just 2 image are Okay.

Comment: @toyotaSupra The first image is the original, second one is the forged one and the third one is the forged one after ELA implementation.